# Why is one part of my object not moving with my rigged bone?

Tags: animation, rigging, objects, bones

[image: This is the Image of the Object in Question.]

First off: I created this little Bendy Bone and want it to move with the arm. So i parented it to the Arm with automatic weights. This happened:

[image]

Only the inner part moves. This makes no sense since the whole arm is ONE Object. Heres a more detailed view:
[image]

It may be because the arm Object consisted of two Objects before that I just joined together, but i dont want to remodel it, unless there is no way around it.

Heres the file:
[image]

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: In general, using autoweights on multiple, separate meshes is not going to work well.  The weights rely on the surface of the meshes to stop weights bleeding out, so you're going to end up with dissimilar weights.  Either make a single manifold mesh, or use other weighting strategies (like, simplest to explain, weight painting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe there is an easier way, but i did this:

1. select your arm, go to edit mode -> mesh -> separate by loose parts, then you got:

[image]

2. now select just the outer parts, M -> collection 3

[image]

3. select the inner part, add boolean modifier -> union, collection, collection 3

[image]

4. apply that modifier
5. delete the armature modifier
6. shift select your armature

[image]

CTRL-P -> with automatic weights

7. hide collection 3

[image]

8. result:

[image]

I think the reason why Blender couldn't "solve" this was, that your mesh wasn't connected at all. So you outer vertices and your inner vertices had no common faces/edges.

Comment: Thanks- You saved the day!

Comment: You are welcome ‼️